# Show that $\mathbb R^2$ is not a vector space under these operations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The operations are

- $(a,b) + (c,d) = (ac, bd)$
- $k(a,b) = (ka, kb)$, where $k$ belongs to $\mathbb R$.

Now I know that it's not a vector space because it's not closed under vector addition; and that to prove this I should make a numerical example that defies the rule.

Now I assumed random values of
$$u = (4,5)$$
$$v = (6,8) $$
but I'm not sure how to continue from there? I wanted to sum them to prove they won't yield the same result but of course they would..I'm kind of confused on how to formulate my counterexample.

Comment: $(a,b) + (c,d) = (ac, bd)$ looks closed to me

Comment: The first couple of things I would suggest checking are: (1) what is the zero vector and (2)  does each vector have an additive inverse with respect to this definition of addition? E.g. given your $u = (4,5)$ is there a $v$ such that $u+v$ equals the zero vector?

Comment: There is also an issue with distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to vector addition

Comment: @Bungo  Try $-u=(\frac14,\frac15)$ since the zero vector is $(1,1)$

Comment: So the problem is with the scalar multiplication not the vector addition?

Comment: @Henry Fair enough. How about $u = (0,0)$? What is its additive inverse?

Comment: @Bungo indeed, or more generally $(a,0)$ or $(0,b)$

Comment: @KadeK The scalar multiplication is the same as the usual one for $\mathbb R^2$, so it isn't inherently problematic. As the examples above show, the addition is the problem, and also the interaction between the scalar multiplication and addition (namely the distributive law) doesn't work, as shown by the example $k=2$, $u = (1,2)$, $v = (2,1)$. Observe that $k(u+v) = 2(2,2) = (4,4)$, whereas $ku + kv = 2(1,2) + 2(2,1) = (2,4) + (4,2) = (8,8)$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact isn´t a vector space, and the contradiction is with the sum  and the product defined.

It´s easy check that the problem is with the scalar product or with the sum , but for be illustrative I´m gonna check $1$ by $1$ property of vector space.Let us check:

**Abelian group**

Let $x=(x_1,x_2),y=(y_1,y_2),z=(z_1,z_2)\in V$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$ Notice that:

*Closure*

$$x+y=(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)\in V$$

*Conmutative*

$$x+y=(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)=(y_1x_1,y_2x_2)=y+x$$

*Neutral element*

There are $e=(1,1)\in V$ such that for any $x\in V$ is true

$$x+e=(x_1\cdot 1, x_2 \cdot 1)=x$$

*Inverse element*

Given $x\in V$ such that $x\neq 0$ there exists $x^{-1}=(\frac{1}{x_1},\frac{1}{x_2})\in V$ such that

$$x+x^{-1}=(x_1\frac{1} \cdot {x_1},x_2 \cdot \frac{1}{x_2})=(1,1)=e$$

Hence $(V,+)$ **is not a abelian group**.

Otherwise $\left(V\setminus (0,0)+\right)$ is **abelian group**

From this part you can also argue that $V$ is not  a vector space since it isn´t a **abelian group** and as Bungo notice use that for $(0,0)$ we can´t find a inverse with the sum.

Now let us check that for $k\in \mathbb{R}$ $V$ is a semigroup.

*Closure*

$$kx=(kx_1,kx_2)\in V$$

*Distributive*

Here there are other new problem wich is because for one hand

$$k(x+y)=k(x_1y_1,x_2y_2)=(kx_1y_1,kx_2y_2)$$ but for the other hand
$$kx+ky=(kx_1,kx_2)+(ky_1,ky_2)=(k^2x_1y_1,k^2x_2y_2)$$

and hance

$(V,+,\cdot)$ **is not a Vector space over $\mathbb{R}$**

For the numerical contour example as above we show is enough  take a $k$ such that $k^2\neq k$ for it considere

$$x=(1,2),y=(1,1),k=2$$

And occur that

$$k(x+y)=k(1,2)=(2,4)$$ but $$kx+ky=(2,4)+(2,2)=(4,8)$$
which are different and then $V$ is not  a vector space.

I hope that it help you, and thanks to *Bungo* for fix my post.

Comment: "Hence $(V,+)$ is an abelian group." - What is the additive inverse of $x = (0,0)$?